# Caching variables in PHP

Tags: php, caching

I've been caching the output buffer of pages lately, but now I want to cache the values of variables.

I have a PHP file that does a bunch of MySQL queries, then fills variables with various data from those queries.

Some of those variables will *never change* but some will change quite often. How can I cache certain variables in this manner? I'm using file-based caching, if it helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing simple caching system in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658815/writing-simple-caching-system-in-php) and numerous others

Comment: Can you clarify your question? If you already have a cache mechanism, what's the problem?

Comment: unless the site is huge, and poorly written (slow) any speed increases will be negligible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yup, file based caching is an option.

There are also other options like [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) and [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)

You should have a look at these as well. If your application is putting a lot of load on your MySQL server, and if your DB is already optimized, caching is a step you can take.

Answer (score 3):

You can dump any variable (including an array) using [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), and the inverse is [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

Dumping to a file would be quite a useless cache solution, you can consider using memcache which can store any variable in memory, but requires some work on server side.

I find that a local mysql with MEMORY tables can be useful, too...

Answer (score 1):

I dont know, how you structured your current caching stuff, so this is just a short template on how you can save any kind of variable (as long as its content is serializeable) to a file.

```
file_put_contents($filename, serialize($variable));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked about file-based caching, both `memcache` and `APC` are no option, although I would certainly recommend both in cases where the stored data is not too large.

For file based caching, I would recommend you to use a caching framework. For example, you could use `Zend_Cache` from the `Zend Framework`. It allows you to store your query results in files by using a nice object oriented interface. Plus, you've got a lot of options, such as validation and serialization. There are also other caching frameworks out there.